# why ncread function in matlab reduce floating point numbers count?

Tags: matlab, netcdf

i have code below in matlab:

```
converted = ncread(this_file, 'U');
disp(converted(50,10,20));
```

and the result is:

> -0.1561

actually the number is -0.15617890 but this code changes the the number of floating numbers. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB displays only 4 digits after the decimal point by default. You can use [`format`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) to display more digits:

```
format long
converted = ncread(this_file, 'U');
disp(converted(50,10,20));
```

Comment: and in next stage i use csvwrite([test,'.txt'],converted); fuction and again the same problem(i have shorter numbers) :( please help me

Comment: @SiamakFarsi [`csvwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) writes a maximum of five significant digits. If you need more precision, you should use [`dlmwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) instead: `dlmwrite([test,'.txt'],converted,'precision',8);`

Comment: dlmwrite  dident work :( . still the same output. both csvwrite and dlmwrite have 7 digits on floating part

Comment: @SiamakFarsi Try `'%.8f'` instead of `8` for the last argument to explicitly set 8 decimal places instead of 8 significant figures (or increase the value; use 9 or higher).

Comment: oh tnxxx gooooooood bless you my angel  @frslm

Comment: dlmwrite([test,'.txt'],converted,'precision',8); did work :))))))))) huray